# case statement using regex like in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

I have a requirement to identify table name inconsistencies across the DWH schemas ,so i have come up with a query which captures table name beginning with and ending with to identify the inconsistencies for table naming standard naming conventions, so that means for each and every schema the table name must begin with it's corresponding schema name defined ,for example

```
STAGE - table name beginning with DS ending with in this schema is no problem
EDW - table name beginning with DE ending with (D,F,L,T,W,W01,W1,W02,W2,W03,W3)
MART - table name beginning with DM ending with (D,F,L,T,W,W01,W1,W02,W2,W03,W3,A,AD,AM,AQ,AY)
```

so there are some special cases where i have some table starting with TBD (To Be Dropped) which is followed by some other characters ,so i would like to classify the tables into 3 categories

**Table classification**

```
1. STANDARD_NAMING_CONV - tables starting with (based on individual schemas STAGE -DS,EDW - DE, Mart - DM) and table ending with EDW - (D,F,L,T,W,W01,W1,W02,W2,W03,W3) and Mart - (D,F,L,T,W,W01,W1,W02,W2,W03,W3,A,AD,AM,AQ,AY)
2. NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV - tables which don't meet the starting and ending from point 1 must be classified into this group
3. TO_BE_DROPPED - consider with tables only beginning with TBD
```

so i have tried the below is my query

**Tested the Query**

```
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       beginning,
       ending,
       CASE WHEN ( beginning, ending ) IN 
       (
              ( 'DS', 'T' ),
              ( 'DB', 'D' ),
              ( 'DB', 'F' ),
              ( 'DB', 'T' ),
              ( 'DB', 'W' ),
              ( 'DE', 'D' ),
              ( 'DE', 'F' ),
              ( 'DE', 'T' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W1' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W01' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W02' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W03' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W1' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W2' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W3' ),
              ( 'DE', 'W1' ),
              ( 'DA', 'D' ),
              ( 'DA', 'F' ),
              ( 'DA', 'T' ),
              ( 'DA', 'W' ),
              ( 'DA', 'W01' ),
              ( 'DA', 'W02' ),
              ( 'DA', 'W03' ),
              ( 'DA', 'W1' ),
              ( 'DA', 'W2' ),
              ( 'DA', 'W3' ),
              ( 'DA', 'A' ),
              ( 'DA', 'AD' ),
              ( 'DA', 'AM' ),
              ( 'DA', 'AQ' ),
              ( 'DA', 'AY' )
       )
           THEN 'STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION'
          WHEN object_name like 'TBD%'
          THEN 'TO_BE_DROPPED'            
       ELSE 'NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION'
    END AS table_classification
FROM   (
  SELECT owner,       
         object_name,
         CASE first_separator
         WHEN 0
         THEN NULL
         ELSE SUBSTR( object_name, 1, first_separator -1 )
         END AS beginning,
         CASE last_separator
         WHEN 0
         THEN NULL
         ELSE SUBSTR( object_name, last_separator + 1 )
         END AS ending
  FROM   (
    SELECT owner,       
           object_name,
           INSTR( object_name, '_', 1 )  AS first_separator,
           INSTR( object_name, '_', -1 ) AS last_separator
    FROM   dba_objects
    WHERE  owner in ('DWH_STAGE_LAYER','DWH_EDW_LAYER','DWH_DATAMART_LAYER')   
    AND    object_type='TABLE'
 and object_name like '%TBD%'
    ORDER BY OWNER DESC,OBJECT_NAME 
  )
);
```

Just for testing purpose i have also introduced a additional filter condition just to see whether the To Be Dropped tables fall under the Table classification - TO_BE_DROPPED ,unfortunately it didn't work , is there a better way to achieve the desired result (please check the **DESIRED RESULT**) using the below case statement using regex_like , can any one incorporate the logic in the above query so that i can test ?

```
case when regex_like(table_name,'^DB_.+_[DFTW]$') will match any name starting with DB_ and ending with D, F, T or W. You can define alternatives with (ABC|DEF|GHI) meaning any of ABC, DEF or GHI. You can combine and nest these, e.g. '^DE_.+_([FT]|W0?[123])$'. (? means zero or one occurrence, + means one or more.) And so on.
```

**Existing Results**

```
OWNER              OBJECT_NAME          BEGINNING   ENDING  TABLE_CLASSIFICATION 
DWH_STAGE_LAYER    DS_CUST_DETAILS_INS  DS          INS     STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION   
DWH_STAGE_LAYER    XY_CUST_DETAILS_INS1 XY          INS     NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_STAGE_LAYER    TBDCUST_DET          TBDCUST     DET     NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_EDW_LAYER      DE_PROD_RECORD_D     DE          D       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_EDW_LAYER      DE_PROD_RECORD_D123  DE          D123    NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_EDW_LAYER      QA_PROD_RECORD_D123  QA          D       NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_EDW_LAYER      TBDPROD_RECORD_AC    TBDPROD     AC      NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_DATAMART_LAYER DM_CONS_REV_F        DM          F       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_DATAMART_LAYER DM_CONS_REV_F45      DM          F45     NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_DATAMART_LAYER TU_CONS_REV_F        TU          F       NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
DWH_DATAMART_LAYER TBDCONS_REV_F1       TBDCONS     F1      NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
```

**DESIRED RESULTS**

```
SNO    OWNER              OBJECT_NAME          BEGINNING   ENDING  TABLE_CLASSIFICATION 
 1  DWH_STAGE_LAYER    DS_CUST_DETAILS_INS     DS          INS     STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION   
 2  DWH_STAGE_LAYER    XY_CUST_DETAILS_INS1    XY          INS     NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
 3  DWH_STAGE_LAYER    TBDCUST_DET             TBDCUST     DET     TO_BE_DROPPED
 4  DWH_EDW_LAYER      DE_PROD_RECORD_D        DE          D       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
 5  DWH_EDW_LAYER      DE_PROD_RECORD_D123     DE          D123    NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
 6  DWH_EDW_LAYER      QA_PROD_RECORD_D123     QA          D       NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
 7  DWH_EDW_LAYER      TBDPROD_RECORD_AC       TBDPROD     AC      TO_BE_DROPPED
 8  DWH_DATAMART_LAYER DM_CONS_REV_F           DM          F       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
 9  DWH_DATAMART_LAYER DM_CONS_REV_F45         DM          F45     NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
10  DWH_DATAMART_LAYER TU_CONS_REV_F           TU          F       NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
11  DWH_DATAMART_LAYER TBDCONS_REV_F1          TBDCONS     F1      TO_BE_DROPPED
```

how to get sno 3,7,11 as expected ? ,any suggestions ,please

basically the idea behind using regexp like is to avoid

1. if there are many schemas it's better not to filter and make the query dynamic

is it also possible to also classify the table categories individually like

```
D - Dimension
F - Facts
L - Lookup tables
T - Technical tables
W - Work tables
W01,W1,W02,W2,W03,W3 - all are additional work tables
A - Aggregated facts
AD - Aggregated facts Daily
AM - Aggregated facts Monthly
AQ - Aggregated facts Quarterly
AY - Aggregated facts Yearly
```

so that it will be easy to classify the other tables into simply non standard

**ISSUE** -

```
While testing further for one group i noticed it is showing NON_STANDARD ,the problem is there are tables beginning with DS_00 in the range DS_99 which are about more than 1000+ ideally it should fall under STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last select, you need to replace

```sql
WHEN (beginning, ending) in (('TBD',' '))
THEN 'TO_BE_DROPPED'
```

by

```sql
WHEN object_name like 'TBD%'
THEN 'TO_BE_DROPPED'
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting , how to reproduce the above code into case when regex_like(table_name,'^DB_.+_[DFTW]$') will match any name starting with DB_ and ending with D, F, T or W. You can define alternatives with (ABC|DEF|GHI) meaning any of ABC, DEF or GHI. You can combine and nest these, e.g. '^DE_.+_([FT]|W0?[123])$'. (? means zero or one occurrence, + means one or more.) And so on. ? any suggestions

Comment: basically instead of all STANDARD_NAMING_CONV i would like to have it into inidividual groups D - Dimension
F - Facts
L - Lookup tables
T - Technical tables
W - Work tables
W01,W1,W02,W2,W03,W3 - all are additional work tables
A - Aggregated facts
AD - Aggregated facts Daily
AM - Aggregated facts Monthly
AQ - Aggregated facts Quarterly
AY - Aggregated facts Yearly     , so that i can capture the counts for example D - dimension , F - Fact and so on...

Comment: You mentionned regex_like whereas it is regexP_like with P before "_".

Comment: @MDO- i have updated the query and desired result , can you please suggest?